# Calling preventDefault on touchmove when the element is already scrolling doesn't have an effect

Tags: ios, safari

On iOS if I call `e.preventDefault()` on `touchmove` when the element is already scrolling it doesn't stop the scrolling. How can I cancel out scrolling mid scroll?

The snippets below will show that it can prevent initial scroll, but i the user scrolls down and then up, it will not stop scrolling on reaching the top.

Since stackoverflow doesn't run scripts on iOS it's also on jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ukxzz6f2/5/

```js
var startPosition;
var elementStartPosition;
var $scrollable = $(".scroll-me");

$scrollable.on("touchstart", function(e){
 startPosition = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  elementStartPosition = $scrollable.scrollTop();
});

$scrollable.on("touchmove scroll", function(e){
  var scrollUp = (startPosition - e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY) < 0;

  if (scrollUp && $scrollable.scrollTop() <= 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $scrollable.css("pointer-events", "none");
  }
});
```

```css
.scroll-me {
  height: 400px;
  background: grey;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-me">
 <div style="height: 1000px;">
   Tall content
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution?